# Variable shows in one function but no another Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope

I am passing PHP sessions to variables to use in Jquery code. Below, there are four areas where I invoke the console log. Console log numbers 1 and 3 reflect the value of the variables no problem. 2 and 4 do not. I needed #4 to have value so I can use the variables in conditions. I guess this could be a scope issue, but I don't see why. Looking for some guidance.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  // GET VARIABLES THROUGH PHP SESSSION
  customerType = '<?php echo $customerType; ?>';
  myClicks = '<?php echo $myClicks; ?>';
  email = '<?php echo $email; ?>';

  console.log('1 ' + email);
  console.log('1 ' + myClicks);
  console.log('1 ' + customerType);

  //SET NUMBER OF ROWS TO DISPLAY AT A TIME

  $(document).ready(function () {

    rowsPerPage = 5;

    // GETTING DATA FROM FUNCTION BELOW
    getData();

    $('#load-more').click(function () {

      console.log('2 ' + email);
      console.log('2 ' + myClicks);
      console.log('2 ' + customerType);

      $('#load-more').html('Loading...');
      var rowID = Number($('#row-id').val());
      var allCount = Number($('#count').val());
      rowID += rowsPerPage;
      if (rowID <= allCount) {
        $('#row-id').val(rowID);
        getData();
      } else {
        $('#load-more').html('End Of Data');
        //$('#load-more').html('');
      }
    });

    /* REQUEST DATA */
    function getData () {

      console.log('3 ' + email);
      console.log('3 ' + myClicks);
      console.log('3 ' + customerType);

      var rowID = $('#row-id').val();
      var allCount = $('#count').val();
      $.ajax({
        url: 'promotions/newest-load-button-data.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: {
          rowID: rowID,
          rowsPerPage: rowsPerPage
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (response) {
          setTimeout(function () {
            loadData(response);
            $('#load-more').html('Load More');
          }, 1000);
        }
      });
    }

    /* LOAD DATA TO PAGE */

    function loadData (data) {

      console.log('4 ' + email);
      console.log('4 ' + myClicks);
      console.log('4 ' + customerType);

      var dataCount = data.length;

      for (var i = 0; i < dataCount; i++) {
        if (i == 0) {
          var allCount = data[i]['allcount'];
          $('#count').val(allCount);
        } else {
          var promoID = data[i]['promoid'];
          var promoName = data[i]['promoname'];
          var promoRefNum = data[i]['promorefnum'];
          var promoType = data[i]['promotype'];
          var theBanner = data[i]['thebanner'];

// Here I will use conditions based on email, customerType, and myClicks

          if (promoType == 'Banner') {
            $('#load-container').append('<div class="row-center-center padding-top-5 padding-bottom-2"><div>' + promoName + '</div></div>');
            $('#load-container').append('<div><div class="wrap-content"><img class="mobile-banner-scale" id="visitor-banner-click" src=' + theBanner + '></div></div>');
          }

          if (promoType == 'Video Banner') {
            $('#load-container').append('<div class="row-center-center padding-top-5 padding-bottom-2"><div>' + promoName + '</div></div>');
            $('#load-container').append('<div><video class="mobile-video-size" id="visitor-banner-click" src=' + theBanner + ' autoplay muted loop></video></div>');
          }
        }

        $('#load-more').html('Load More');
      }
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: It's hard to say without the HTML data. You have 2 on a click event, but we don't have it. I'd put a minimum working example via snippet for us to diagnose. :)

Comment: Probably is a scope issue. Try moving `function loadData()` to the global scope (same scope as `customerType`). Named functions get hoisted, anonymous functions don't.

Comment: Definitely scope.

Answer (score 0):

> As of jQuery 3.0 the recommended way to add a ready handler is the
>   first method, $(fn). As noted in the Event section, the
>   $(document).on("ready", fn) event form has slightly different
>   semantics and was removed in jQuery 3.0.

This code snippet works using the recommended document ready handler.

```js
    
        jQuery(function(){  //document.ready

            console.log('2 ' + email);
            console.log('2 ' + myClicks);
            console.log('2 ' + customerType);
            loadData('something');
        });

        customerType = 'test1';
        myClicks = 'test2';
        email = 'test3';

        function loadData (data) {
    
            console.log('4 ' + email);
            console.log('4 ' + myClicks);
            console.log('4 ' + customerType);
       }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I just normally use this for my jQuery code.  It prevents conflict errors with the $ primarily.  But also, does it not create a closure which then allows access to the variables he was trying to access?   I dunno, all I know is it worked when I tested it lol

Comment: I'm asking more because a document ready is essentially a more distinct version of an IIFE, and a usage of `jQuery(function($){})` would provide the scope reduction, and the ensurance that `jQuery = $` due to it being passed in.

Comment: You are correct,  I didn't realize since jquery 3.0, the only recommended way to do this is with jQuery(fn), I will update my answer accordingly, thanks!

Comment: Err, I don't want you to take it like I'm saying your approach is wrong, or that my suggestion is the only recommended way.  I'm just trying to point out the comparison of what an IIFE does and what a document ready does, and where their functionality has things in common.  I'm absolutely not saying you are wrong.

Comment: It works without the outer IIFE using the ready handler you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

It was definitely a scope issue. I found that if I called the function in the global, I could get the response I needed. But there was a data length error. I decided to call the value of the session on the php data page and include it in the JSON array to pass through ajax along with the other variables that are needed in the load. So it works now, different way. I appreciate everyone's take.

Answer (score -1):

```
// GET VARIABLES THROUGH PHP SESSSION
customerType = "where are customers";
myClicks = "element clicked";
email = "email sent";

console.log('1 ' + email);
console.log('1 ' + myClicks);
console.log('1 ' + customerType);

//SET NUMBER OF ROWS TO DISPLAY AT A TIME

$(document).ready(function() {

    rowsPerPage = 5;

    // GETTING DATA FROM FUNCTION BELOW
    getData();

    $("#load-more").click(function() {

        console.log('2 ' + email);
        console.log('2 ' + myClicks);
        console.log('2 ' + customerType);

        $('#load-more').html('Loading...');
        var rowID = Number($("#row-id").val());
        var allCount = Number($("#count").val());
        rowID += rowsPerPage;
        if (rowID <= allCount) {
            $("#row-id").val(rowID);
            getData();
        } else {
            $('#load-more').html('End Of Data');
            //$('#load-more').html('');
        }
    });

    /* REQUEST DATA */
    function getData() {
        console.log('3 ' + email);
        console.log('3 ' + myClicks);
        console.log('3 ' + customerType);

        loadData();
    }

    /* LOAD DATA TO PAGE */

    function loadData(data) {
        console.log('4 ' + email);
        console.log('4 ' + myClicks);
        console.log('4 ' + customerType);
    }
});
```

Everything seems to be fine, your variables email,myClicks,customerType are printing values in console, you need to check once again, I think the issue is something else, Please check once again.